# Set unit precision and decimals

Tags: units

I'm working in millimeters and I don't need anything smaller than 1mm. When I extrude or move a plane etc to say 100mm, I notice it's actually something like 100.22mm after checking the measurement box. I don't need the 0.22mm precision, and I fear it'll mess up my model later on when I use that corner as a reference point. How do I tell Blender to rid the decimals as I don't need anything more precise than a whole number.

Comment: Hello :). Just to clear this up - why not just manually enter the 100 mm? Works just fine for me...

Comment: It's mostly because when I do a "loop cut", it only gives you a "Factor" number to punch in as opposed to typing in an actual mm measurement from one end. It does show the measurement from one end when you are sliding your mouse though, which is why I ask the above question and hence the problem.

Comment: Not the perfect way around it but I managed to figure out something... Basically hold Ctrl while sliding the loop will set it to increments. After that use the Move tool to adjust the measurement and enter the numbers into the measurement box.